# How to `zcompile` global (system-wide) zsh scripts?

Tags: shell, zsh, dotfiles, global

For my local dotfiles I have this snippet at the end of my `.zshrc`:

```sh
for f in ~/.zshrc ~/.zshenv ; do
    [ "${f}"(:A) -ot "$f".zwc ] || zcompile "$f"
done
```

This ensures that these scripts are always precompiled if modified.

But global scripts that I `source` are much more heavy-weight, for example `/usr/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh`, `/usr/share/doc/fzf/examples/completion.zsh` or `/usr/share/doc/fzf/examples/key-bindings.zsh`.

Is there a good solution how to `zcompile` these, ideally globally for all users? Or should I just resort to copy them locally into my `$HOME` and `zcompile` there?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you mean with "good solution". Naive approach: Have maybe a  cronjob (periodically or on system-boot) to compile the system-wide files the same way you do it with your user's files?